# Toggle between Html5 appcache when server if offline and use server when its up

Tags: html, offline, html5-appcache

I am using HTML5 appcache in my webapplicaiton. Basic idea is to serve content from appcache when server is offline and as soon as server is up , application can take content from server.

Is there a way to detect if server if offline and toggle between appcache and server.

Comment: Thats what HTML5 appcache does...

Comment: No if appcache is used , content is always taken from appache unless there is a refresh.

Comment: But appcache does support pushing new content to the client if there is an update by making changes to manifest file...

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. You have a couple of options:

1. So long as you update the cache manifest properly when there's a content change in your site, as users 'go online' this update will be detected and the application will cache the relevant content
2. If there are areas of your site that simply should not be cached *ever*, that's what the `NETWORK` section of the cache manifest is for.

Following on from #2, conceivably you could also then combine online-only elements of your site with cached content and serve different items depending on the online state.

(Note that when it comes to detecting whether a browser is off-line or not, opinions vary across the different browser vendors. It may be wise to use a library for this, e.g. [offline.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline)).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no. Per the appcache spec, applicationcache does not work if the server can't be contacted.

> Otherwise, if fetching the manifest fails in some other way (e.g. the server returns another 4xx or 5xx response or equivalent, or there is a DNS error, or the connection times out, or the user cancels the download, or the parser for manifests fails when checking the magic signature), or if the server returned a redirect, or if the resource is labeled with a MIME type other than text/cache-manifest, then run the cache failure steps.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html)